# Select only documents with id value not in the collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection `ft` with a number of records in it. However,i want to exclude certain ids that i have in a comma delimited list.

I am trying to do the following

```
var ids = [ "RQcWthREHBTfkybMy", "jiPrzQQWxbN5a8pEC", "5oFxC68WEggYzY7ah" ]
db.collection.find( { _id: { $ne: ids } } )
```

but i can only manage to exclude `RQcWthREHBTfkybMy` which is the first id in my list.

Comment: Use [**`$nin`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/) as `db.ft.find({_id:{$nin:["RQcWthREHBTfkybMy","jiPrzQQWxbN5a8pEC","5oFxC68WEggYzY7ah"]}})`

Comment: @chridam Thanks. That did work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`$ne`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/) query operator behavior when the specified value is array is quite different from the the [`$eq`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/) operator. To check if a field value is not in the specified array you need to use the [`$nin`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/) query operator.

```
var ids = [ "RQcWthREHBTfkybMy", "jiPrzQQWxbN5a8pEC", "5oFxC68WEggYzY7‌​ah" ]
db.collection.find( { "_id": { "$nin": ids } } )
```